# Drawing a line plot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I am really new to R and I struggling to create a line plot. I would like to have on the x-axis time and on a y-axis percentages and to color the graph based on 'homemotherandchild' variable. I would like to have 2 lines one line that show the timing of ' Other activity or occupancy pattern' and another line that shows the timing of  "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child".  I  tried to add one line  on top of a stacked barplot however it won't work.

```
structure(list(time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 
25L, 25L), .Label = c("04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", 
"04:50", "05:00", "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", 
"06:00", "06:10", "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", 
"07:10", "07:20", "07:30", "07:40", "07:50", "08:00", "08:10", 
"08:20", "08:30", "08:40", "08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", 
"09:30", "09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", 
"10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", 
"11:50", "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", 
"13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", 
"14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", 
"15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", 
"16:30", "16:40", "16:50", "17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", 
"17:40", "17:50", "18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", 
"18:50", "19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", 
"20:00", "20:10", "20:20", "20:30", "20:40", "20:50", "21:00", 
"21:10", "21:20", "21:30", "21:40", "21:50", "22:00", "22:10", 
"22:20", "22:30", "22:40", "22:50", "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", 
"23:30", "23:40", "23:50", "00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", 
"00:40", "00:50", "01:00", "01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", 
"01:50", "02:00", "02:10", "02:20", "02:30", "02:40", "02:50", 
"03:00", "03:10", "03:20", "03:30", "03:40", "03:50"), class = "factor"), 
    homemotherandchild = c("Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern", "Activity: Time Spent with mother and child  ; Occupacy pattern: At home, with spouse/partner and child", 
    "Other activity or occupancy pattern"), n = c(706L, 196L, 
    713L, 189L, 712L, 190L, 711L, 191L, 710L, 192L, 707L, 195L, 
    709L, 193L, 706L, 196L, 701L, 201L, 693L, 209L, 693L, 209L, 
    689L, 213L, 683L, 219L, 676L, 226L, 669L, 233L, 653L, 249L, 
    642L, 260L, 625L, 277L, 599L, 303L, 597L, 305L, 576L, 326L, 
    547L, 355L, 528L, 374L, 510L, 392L, 475L, 427L), Percent = c(0.96978021978022, 
    0.269230769230769, 0.979395604395604, 0.259615384615385, 
    0.978021978021978, 0.260989010989011, 0.976648351648352, 
    0.262362637362637, 0.975274725274725, 0.263736263736264, 
    0.971153846153846, 0.267857142857143, 0.973901098901099, 
    0.26510989010989, 0.96978021978022, 0.269230769230769, 0.962912087912088, 
    0.276098901098901, 0.951923076923077, 0.287087912087912, 
    0.951923076923077, 0.287087912087912, 0.946428571428571, 
    0.292582417582418, 0.938186813186813, 0.300824175824176, 
    0.928571428571429, 0.31043956043956, 0.918956043956044, 0.320054945054945, 
    0.896978021978022, 0.342032967032967, 0.881868131868132, 
    0.357142857142857, 0.858516483516483, 0.380494505494505, 
    0.822802197802198, 0.416208791208791, 0.820054945054945, 
    0.418956043956044, 0.791208791208791, 0.447802197802198, 
    0.751373626373626, 0.487637362637363, 0.725274725274725, 
    0.513736263736264, 0.700549450549451, 0.538461538461538, 
    0.652472527472527, 0.586538461538462)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest next `ggplot2` approach arranging elements for easy understanding. With `df` being the `dput()` data you included, here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(x=time,y=Percent,group=homemotherandchild,color=homemotherandchild))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'top')
```

Output:

[image]